# Select rows with max(id) having max(payment_date)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been trying to get the max(id) for the max(payment_date) of every account_id, as there are instances where there's different entries for the same max(payment_date). The ids are the payment references for the account_ids. So every account_id needs to have one entry with the max(payment_date) and the max(id) for that date. Problem is that there are entries where the max(id) for the account_id is not for the max(payment_date), or I would have just used max(id). The code below is not working because of this, since it will exclude entries where the max(id) is not for the max(payment_date). Thanks in advance.

```
select *
from (
  select payments.* 
  from (
    select account_id, max(payment_date) as last_payment, max(id) as last_payment1 
    from energy.payments 
    where state = 'success' 
      and amount_pennies > 0 
      and description not ilike '%credit%' 
      group by account_id 
  ) as last_payment_table
  inner join energy.payments as payments 
         on payments.account_id = last_payment_table.account_id
        and payments.payment_date = last_payment_table.last_payment
        and payments.id = last_payment_table.last_payment1
) as paymentst1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct on`.  I can't really follow your query (sample data is such a big help!)  But the idea is:

```
select distinct on (p.account_id) p.*
from energy.payments p
order by p.account_id, p.payment_date desc, p.id desc;
```

You can add additional logic for filtering or whatever.  That logic is not explained in your question but is suggested by the code you've included.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand the question, but I *think* you mean this:

---

```
SELECT *
FROM payments  p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM payments  nx
        WHERE nx.account_id = p.account_id      -- same account
        AND nx.payment_date >= p.payment_date   -- same or more recent date
        AND nx.id > p.id                        -- higher ID
        );
```

---

Or, using a window function:

---

```
select *
from (
  select * 
    , row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY account_id
                        ORDER BY payment_date DESC,id DESC) as rn
    from energy.payments
    where state = 'success' 
      and amount_pennies > 0 
      and description not ilike '%credit%' 
) x
WHERE x.rn=1
        ;
```